# Copy shortcut changed as Ctrl+P on Windows 11, How to revert back to Ctrl+C?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste, windows-11

Somehow "copy" shortcut changed as Ctrl+P, I don't know how but I think it changed after I upgrade to Windows 11. How to revert back shortcuts to default?

[image: Screenshot of Copy command]

Comment: Why is Windows Terminal in English and everything is in another language?  What language packs do you have installed?  Were you using a different language pack when you Windows 10 installed? The context menu is fairly different on Windows 11 compared to Windows 10 there will be differences  Some of the behavior from Windows 10 can no longer be reproduced on Windows 11, based on what i see, I am 99% sure you have fallen into one of those cases.

Comment: If you ignore the right context menu, and simply select the item, and hit "CTRL+C" does it copy the file?  The only reason the keyboard shortcut would be different is due to the language.  [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec) is a list of all the default keyboard shortcuts that exist in Windows 11.

Comment: Which language are you using?